# How to write MySQL query in text file and run in linux

Tags: shell-script, mysql

I would like to call a .sql file from a .sh file in linux. The .sql file will contain queries to MySQL database.

I am able to call the .sql file by running .sh file in linux, but the sql query is not working. Below is my syntax. The select statement is throwing below error.

```
./sample.sql: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `from'
```

sample.sh file:

```
echo "this is shellscript calling sql"
./sample.sql
```

sample.sql file:

```
set pages 999
set lines 999
set colsep |
select * from sampletable;
```

expected result should be similar to a normal select * from xxx statement

Answer (score 3):

Instead of sourcing the sql-file, you need to pass it to `mysql`:

```
mysql -u user -psecret < /full/path/to/sample.sql
```